# Red dots over the LED monitor

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi, adapter, display-driver

What I have:-

```
1x  GTX N560 Ti Hawk
1x  DVI-I to VGA converter
1x LED Monitor from LG (I don't remember the model name)
```

I am getting red dots all over the screen, I am confirmed that its not the problem of monitor because during the BIOS boot there is no sign of red dots, but as soon as I enter windows booting screen, the dots come. So its either the fault of graphics card(which I don't think because during BIOS boot no red dots seems to be there) or its the loose/ damaged cables or graphics driver problem

these red dots appeared when I was playing battlefield 4 and battlefield 4 collapsed with a constant buzzing sound, indicating that the operating system has frozen, I highly think its because of graphics driver because after the game collapsed I restarted PC and the driver didn't start up. I have [this](http://www.nvidia.in/Download/driverResults.aspx/102097/en-in) graphics card driver

I have connected the DVI-I to VGA converter to the graphics card and then a VGA to VGA cable is connected to the monitor, So it goes like -> GTX N560 Ti Hawk -> DVI-I to VGA converter -> VGA to VGA connecting the Monitor. I did experience a transparent red blue color change a couple of days ago but that went away and I ignored it. Searching on web said that its the problem of loose cable/ damaged cable adapter, if so then I already got a VGA cable ready.

Comment: Can you take a photo that depicts the problem and link to it here?

Comment: Sounds a lot like your video card might be dying. Why are you using VGA tho? HDMI or DVI is super common in older monitors and superior

Comment: I have seen this with a bad cpu as well, though, so if you can borrow a different video card to rule out/rule in the card as the source, you'd be saving some time and money.

Answer (score 1):

- DVI-VGA converter might be bad or cables not 100% properly connected into it (look for bent pins).  Try replacing it.  This is likely the issue.
- Make sure your graphics card is securely plugged in and set properly in the case.
- Try switching cables.
- Try connecting to an alternate monitor.
- Try moving graphics card to another x16 slot of your motherboard has one.

If none of the above help, your graphics hardware is having a problem and should be replaced.